# Can we read documents inside sharePoint like .doc, .ppt etc without saving them in documents library in sharepoint

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-server, document, document-set, office-web-apps

Can we read documents inside SharePoint like `.doc`, `.ppt` and `.xls` etc without saving them in Documents Library in SharePoint?

I want to embed these documents in SharePoint Page and don't want to save inside SharePoint as those documents are in some server and I am reading them using virtual directory and `http Service`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Straight forward way to do this. Even if the document resides in Document Library.

One way is to read the document into memory and convert it to web page (html) and load it into a `div` or `panel`

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Convert-Office-Word-Document-to-HTML-and-display-it-in-browser-in-ASP.Net.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507068/Microsoft-Interop-API-to-convert-the-doc-docx-dot

Comment: I know if we have document inside library and OWA enabled in sharepoint then we can simply copy and paste the URL or path of document in page viewer file or webpage location box. To display file inside sharepoint page.  Like:http://intranet.netelligent.com/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=/Documents/Business_Economics_H7J08ej7Qt(1).docx&action=default

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: But the issue i am facing when i try to read documents from server. like:  //xx.xx.x.xxx/Test/Mytest.pdf   that's why i wanted to read these files using virtual directory but no luck :(          http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/143475/read-hard-drive-files-inside-sharepoint-page/143483#143483